# How to split a string in TSQL by space character

Tags: t-sql

I have a difficult task in TSQL that I can't seem to find a simple way to do. I am trying to use CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(sentence, ' '), but I can only get one word to the method. Can you please help? Thank you.

Sample sentence:

1. I need to split strings using TSQL.
2. This approach is traditional, and is supported in all versions and editions of SQL Server.

Desired answer:

1. I need
2. to split
3. strings using
4. TSQL.

Desired Answer:

1. This approach
2. is traditional
3. , and
4. is supported
5. in all
6. versions and
7. editions of
8. SQL Server.

Comment: So you want to split on every-other space character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

First add a space to any comma (you want a comma treated as a word), then split the string on each space into rows using some Json, then assign groups to pair each row using *modulo* and *lag over()*, then aggregate based on the groups:

```
declare @s varchar(100)='This approach is traditional, and is supported in all versions and editions of SQL Server';

select Result = String_Agg(string,' ') within group (order by seq)
from (
  select j.[value] string, Iif(j.[key] % 2 = 1, Lag(seq) over(order by seq) ,seq) gp, seq
  from OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(Replace(@s,',',' ,'), ' ', '","'), '"]')) j
  cross apply(values(Convert(tinyint,j.[key])))x(seq)
)x
group by gp;
```

Result:

[image]

See <kbd>[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4c1e35388131497ecc56601f79d5778)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Stu. I really appreciate your speedy help on this. It works great. Is it possible to  ignore the double quotes on the string?

Comment: double quotes? There are no double quotes in your sample data, sorry I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I meant if the string has a double quote characters, the error message will display. 

declare @s varchar(100)='"A true character is developed only when a man acrosses thousands of hurdles"';

Comment: Ah ok I get you; So this is an easy fix, because the json string uses double quotes they need to be escaped which you can do by doubleing them up (just like you would for single quotes) - `from OpenJson(Concat('["', Replace(Replace(Replace(@s,',',' ,'),'"','""'), ' ', '","'), '"]')) j`

Comment: Actually my bad this doesn't work in all sitations - replace the quotes with `\"` should work.